# "Could not load file or assembly SqlPackageBase" error when trying to query in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've just installed SSMS 17.2.  I'm connecting to a SQL Server DB using a VPN.  I can connect in fine, but when I click to query, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'SqlPackageBase, Version=14.100.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image: SSMS Error]

I don't get the error when I connect to a local SQL Server instance so I'm guessing it has something to do with the VPN connection?

I did do a search of my hard drive for the "sqlpackagebase.dll" and find that it's in the SQL Server files.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Odds are you'll need assistance from your network admin or VPN admin. Are you using Windows authentication or SQL Server login?

Comment: One suggestion you could try [here](https://vicnsi.wordpress.com/2014/12/28/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-sqm-version10-0-0-0-cultureneutral-publickeytoken89845dcd8080cc91-or-one-of-its-dependencies-sqlmgmt/). Back up any files you replace first obviously.

Comment: SQL server login, but it's via the vpn so I had to set up a powershell login and then "Run as different user" when I start the program (SSMS).  I was able to successfully connect via Power BI, but I'm not as familiar with that tool as I am SSMS.  I have put in a ticket with the folks I'm trying to connect to.  I'll try the other suggestion as well.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Heard back from the IT folks - they suggested I load an earlier version of SSMS - everything works fine.  I guess the newest version still has some bugs to work out :)

Comment: Similar issue reported on MSDN : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7a71121c-83b1-49b4-ad30-3a5f20e7afbf/smo-2017-microsoftsqlserverbatchparserdll-load-error?forum=sqlsmoanddmo&prof=required